# Problems with dynamic Label in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a GUI that shows how many People are using our Swimming Pool.
Sadly I am not able to find my mistake.
Could anybody help? :-(

````
import pickle
import time


class GUI():
    

   
        
    def __init__(self, visitors):
         self.visitors = visitors
         self.rest = 15-int(self.visitors)
         print("bin hier")
         self.window = Tk()
         self.pzahlvar= StringVar(value="{0}/15".format(self.visitors))
         self.restvar = StringVar(value="Es können noch {0} Gäste eintreten".format(self.rest))
         self.ueberschrift = Label(self.window, text="Aktuelle Badegäste:", font=("Arial bold", 72)).pack(pady=50)
         self.personenzahl = Label(self.window, textvariable=self.pzahlvar, font=("Arial bold", 150))
         self.personenzahl.pack(pady=90)
         if self.rest>0:
                self.restgaeste = Label(self.window, textvariable=self.restvar, font=("Arial bold", 65))
         else:
                self.restgaeste = Label(self.window, text="Die maximale Gästezahl ist erreicht. Aktuell kein Eintritt".format(rest), font=("Arial bold", 72))
                self.window.bg("red")
         self.restgaeste.pack(pady=100)
         self.setPLabel()
         self.window.mainloop()
 
    def setPLabel(self):
        self.personenzahl = Label(self.window, textvariable=self.pzahlvar, font=("Arial bold", 150))
        self.personenzahl.after(1000, setPLabel)
        
    def setPzahlVar(self, zahl):
        self.pzahlvar.value="{0}/15".format(zahl)```
````

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverfow =) Could you provide some more information? e.g. is there an exception? could you describe the problem?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? What does it do that is different from what you expect?

Comment: The Labels (Personenzahl) is not getting updated. It always shows the Number it gets initiated with :-(

Comment: @SGLeng did you try `self.pzahlvar.set()` instead of value?

Answer (score 0):

Is `__init__` ever called? (Did you call e.g. gui = GUI(15); ?) 15 is the number of visitors.

```
        self.personenzahl.after(1000, setPLabel)
```

Doesn't make sense to me. Why do you try to call setPLabel again after 1000ms?

Is ``` (Last line) really in your code?

Comment: the ```was not intended. Sorry! I planned to call it again because it should be updated. I called it and it does work. The only Problem ist that i cant seem to find out how to update the lable to show the actual number of people.

Comment: Did you update pZahlVar? You should call setPzahlVar() and setPLabel from your main. E.g. gui = GUI(1); setPzahlVar(2); setPLabel();